# composer is disabled for this thread on facebook messenger

Tags: facebook-chatbot, gupshup

Hi can i ask if what happen on my chatbot on facebook messenger? here's the problem says on chatbox "composer is disabled for this thread ".

I've created BOT using Gupshop ,

Comment: can you share more details. Like bot name and a screenshot of what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have the composer disabled in your persistent menu settings:

https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/get-started-button-persistent-menu-fb#PersistentMenu

Comment: Hi guys, just to inform I've fixed already, I've changed my JSON menu file {"disableinput: true"} into {"disableinput: false"} , Thanks for comments (y)

Answer (score 1):

just to inform I've fixed already, I've changed my JSON menu file {"disableinput: true"} into {"disableinput: false"} , Thanks for comments (y)

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is from the Sample in document :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/persistent-menu/

Change `"composer_input_disabled":` to  `false`

```
"persistent_menu": [{
    "locale": "default",
    "composer_input_disabled": false,
    "call_to_actions": [{
        "type": "postback",
        "title": "Quiz me!",
        "payload": "MENU_QUIZ_ME"
      },
      {
        "type": "postback",
        "title": "Help",
        "payload": "MENU_HELP"
      }
    ]
  }]
```