# Disable text input when facebook messenger sends buttons/quick_replies along with message

Tags: node.js, facebook-messenger-bot

I am using facebook messenger bot buliding with Nodejs. Can I disable text input using an API when the bot sends a message within a button? Is there any strategy possible when the bot only the message, input remains enabled and disabled when sends buttons/quick_replies?

Let me some add picture below to make my query most clear and
**I need text input disabled where placeholder "type a message is written"**

[image]

Comment: I guess not, the buttons is only suggestions. When the user clicks on it, it will be sent as a typed message. The best approach is validate the input and send a "invalid option"

Comment: okay , i got it.. i need to validate the input

Comment: I guess, we have a way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47386141/composer-is-disabled-for-this-thread-on-facebook-messenger , https://medium.com/@sydlawrence/facebook-just-launched-a-major-update-to-the-messenger-platform-3b29e7fa49e7. I am not sure, if it will solve the use case of OP, but there is some way to acheive disabling composer.

Comment: No, you cant dynamically disable input at the moment. You can disable input globally.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with Facebook Messenger. As suggested by Milton, you should validate incoming text and decide if the user meant certain input. You should be aware of typos and case however.

In my experience, when we don't get the user input we repeat the question with explanation and give quick replies again.